# calculate table th width in percentage instead of pixel in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to calculate table th width in percentage and assign that width to table tbody td using javascript ?

```
 $('#headerwidth').find('thead th').each(function(){
  var rowval = $(this).outerWidth()+'px' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to write one loop inside current loop on `thead`:

```
 $('#headerwidth').find('thead th').each(function(){
     var rowval = $(this).outerWidth()+'px' ;
     $('#headerwidth').find('tbody tr td').each(function(){
        $(this).css("width", rowval)
     });
});
```